# How to compare 2 indexes in Knockout.js foreach?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Simple question: In the ViewModel I have an array of values that I want to iterate over, let's call them 'jobs'. Each job is `{type: myType, name: myName}`.
I want to put an `<hr />` between job types to separate them. I tried the following, but I think something is screwed up with my syntax:

```
<!-- ko foreach: jobs -->
  <div class="job" data-bind="text: name"></div>
  <!-- ko if: ($index() > 0 && $parent[$index()].type != $parent[$index() - 1].type) -->
    <hr />
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Without the `<!-- ko if -->` it all works well, and I get a nice list.
With that `if`, I'm getting the first 2 jobs names printed, followed by an `hr` (wrong, since I have 6 jobs of the first type), followed by this error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined;
>   Bindings value: if: ($index() > 0 && $parent[$index()].type != $parent[$index() - 1].type)

For the record, there are 18 jobs, of 3 different types.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend such 'if' logic be done outside the template for an example in the view model if possible. View template should ideally hold structure and data binding attributes.. not control flow.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but it was just easier that way. What approach would you recommend? A computed fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$parent` in this context is the object that contains the property `jobs`.  So you'd have to index into the `$parent.jobs`.

```
<!-- ko if: ($index() > 0 && $data.type != $parent.jobs[$index() - 1].type) -->
    <hr />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: It's not an obseravle array, just a simple array. Tried your code and got a TypeError: object is not a function.

Comment: Oh no, I got it.  I see where I went wrong.  I also incorrectly thought `$data` was an observable, it's the actual object itself.